# Regex for search and get the src of a image

Tags: python, html, regex

Assume I am having a html string containing the following code snippet.

```
... <img class="employee thumb" src="http://localhost/services/employee1.jpg" /> ...
```

I want to search whether this tag is available and if so get the src url. `<img class="employee thumb"` can be used to uniquely identify the tag.

How to do this in python?

Comment: Why use regular expressions when [excellent HTML parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) are available? `soup = BeautifulSoup(yourpage)`, then `image = soup.select('img.employee.thumb')`.

Comment: Maybe using regexp for parsing html is not the best approach. This Answer talk about that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/661140

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am getting the html using `page =urllib2.urlopen(url)` and `yourpage=page.read()`. Then I couldn't parse the html as you mentioned. Any thoughts?

Comment: Although [you could do so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272), I do not recommend that route.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular Expression :

```
>>> import re
>>> str =  '<img class="employee thumb" src="http://localhost/services/employee1.jpg" />'
>>> if re.search('img class="employee thumb"', str):
...     print re.findall ( 'src="(.*?)"', s, re.DOTALL)
... 
['http://localhost/services/employee1.jpg']
```

Using lxml :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring("""
... <html>
...     <img class="employee thumb" src="http://localhost/services/employee1.jpg" />
... </html>
... """)
>>> print root.xpath("//img[@class='employee thumb']/@*")[1]
http://localhost/services/employee1.jpg
```

Comment: The `lxml` version isn't much use; it doesn't actually search for the `img` tag in a larger document.

Comment: No, you still only test if `root` is the image tag. The OP has a larger chunk of HTML, not just containing the `<img>` tag.

Comment: I think the input is in string format as mentioned in the question. So i think the only concern is about getting 'src' if class attrib is 'employee thumb'.

Comment: No, the OP's first sentence is *Assume I am having a html string **containing the following code snippet***, emphasis mine. Note the `...` ellipsis in the HTML sample as well.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am saying, it is specifically mention in the question itself.
Assume I am having a html string containing the following code snippet.
... <img class="employee thumb" src="http://localhost/services/employee1.jpg" /> .

Comment: <img> tag is not the root of my html string. It just a part of it as mentioned.

Comment: @Yasita, I have edited it, now <img> is not the root.